# What is the best way to have user specific numbering in Django?

Tags: django

I'm making a web site for a friend for a small business, and for each user, I want them to be able to access their orders by number which starts from 1 for each user, but in the backend this should be a global numbering. So for each user, their first order will be at `/orders/1/` and so on. Is there a consensus on how this should be achieved in general? Way I see it, I can do this 2 ways:

Store the number in another column in the orders table. I'd prefer not to do this because I'm not entirely sure how to handle deletions without going through and updating all the records of the user. If someone knows the edge cases I need to handle, I might go with this.

OR

For every queryset I make when getting the orders page for each user I handle the numbering, benefit of this is that it will always give the correct numbering, especially if I just do it in the template. Right now this seems easier, but I have a feeling this would give rise to problems in the future. Main problem I see is I'm not sure how to make it link to the correct url without the primary key being in that url.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to store MyUser in a separate app, say accounts

```
class MyUser(BaseUser):
    # extra fields
```

And store Order in a separate app, say order

```
from accounts.models import MyUser

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    order_num = models.IntegerField()
    # other fields
```

keep update this order_num by the count of orders the user has made.
to get the count,
count = Order.objects.filter(user==request.user).count()